# Google Geocoder and 'this' reference in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript

I'm having a problem trying to get a reference to the main object after do a call to geocoder.

```
export class Oferta{
   _self: any;
   geocoder: any;
   contructor (){
      this._self = this;
      this.geocoder = null;
   }

   geolocalizate(){
      var _this = this;
      var address = "Home";
      this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      this.geocoder.geocode({
         'address': address
      }, function(results,status){
          // 'this' here is a reference to 'window'
          // _self and _this are 'undefined' 
      });
   }
}
```

I'm not able to find out a way to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an arrow function `=>` instead of `function`. Also *don't* do `_this` as typescript reserves that for lexical scoping. Complete:

```
export class Oferta{
   _self: any;
   geocoder: any;
   constructor (){
      this._self = this;
      this.geocoder = null;
   }

   geolocalizate = () => {        // ARROW 

      var address = "Home";
      this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      this.geocoder.geocode({
         'address': address
      }, (results,status) => {   // ARROW 
          // use `this` 
      });
   }
}
```

More : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Also you misspelled `constructor`, that explains why `_self` is wrong.

Comment: Works like a charm. I ignored this approach. Sorry about the typing error ('contructor')